# Convert a string into variable

Tags: python, string, exec

What I am trying to do is
`x = "string1"`
`y = "string2"`

and output should be

`string1 = "string2"`

I have tried:
`exec("%s = %s" % (x,y))`

If I put y =2 #or any number
It will give the desired result but when I assign a string (y= "anystring" it tries to execute anystring and gives error:
 `NameError( name "anystring" is not defined`

Maybe I don't know exactly how to use the exec command. Any kind of help/suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y value should be in quotes.

```
>>> x = "string1"
>>> y = "string2"
>>> exec("%s = '%s'" % (x,y))
>>> string1
'string2'
```